# changing linux memory protection

Tags: linux, memory-management

Is there a way to check which memory protection machenizem is used by the OS?

I have a program that fails with segmentation fault, in one computer (ubuntu) but not in another (RH6).

One of the explanations was memory protection mechanizem used by the OS.
Is there a way I can find / change it?

Thanks,

Comment: is a programm written in c ? Because maybe also glibc could act like this.

Comment: Why don't you fix your program to stop trying to access memory it doesn't own instead?

Comment: You could try to use gdb and see where it fails (you must enable debug information while compiling your program, though).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to learn more about [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR).

Then you could study the role and usage of [mmap & munmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) system calls (also [mprotect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect)). They are the syscalls used to retrieve memory (e.g. to implement `malloc` & `free`), sometimes with obsolete syscalls like `sbrk` (which is increasingly useless).

You should use the `gdb`  debugger (its `watch` command may be handy), and the [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) utility. [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) could also be useful.

Look also inside the [/proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) pseudo file system. Try to understand what

```
cat /proc/self/maps
```

is telling you (about the process running that `cat`). Look also inside `/proc/$(pidof your-program)/maps`

consider also using the [pmap](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) utility.

If it is your own source code, always compile it with all warnings and debuggiing info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and improve it till the compiler don't give any warnings. Use a recent version of `gcc`  (ie 4.7) and of `gdb` (i.e. 7.4).